# Ajax Jquery / JavaScript create HTML Elements when data is greater than 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML element that I am populating with divs & data with JSON returned from a PHP script. The data is constantly updating so I am using Eventsouce (sse).

```
<div class="row state-overview" id="statusCount"> </div>

let fsource;
function getStatus() {
    if (typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
        try {
            fsource.removeEventListener("status", stream, false);
        } catch (ex) {
        }
        fsource = new EventSource("-PHP FILE-");
        fsource.addEventListener("status", stream, false);
    } else {
        console.log("Oh no");
    }
}
function stream(e) {
    let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    let html = '';
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        html += '<div class="col-lg-2 panel ' + key + ' ">';
        html += '<p>' + key + '</p>';
        html += '<label>' + value + '</label>';
        html += '</div>';
    });
     $('#statusCount').html(html);
}
getStatus();
```

This works perfectly, however, I am trying to hide / not show elements where the value = 0.

A sample of the JSON looks like so:

```
event: status
data: {"Online": 2, "Stopped": 3, "Alarm": 0, "Offline": 0}
```

Unfortunately I can't change the PHP to manipulate what data gets returned,
so any JavaScript or Jquery Solutions would be great - cheers!

Comment: Which part of this problem are you having trouble with? You are asking for and getting data. You are free to examine this data before deciding how to display it. If the value is 0 then simply apply some style rule that will prevent the element's display.

Comment: I have added a few different style rules but I am either showing all the divs or none of the divs :(

Comment: In the each loop, can't you do `if (value === 0) continue;` and skip that iteration?

Comment: Hi @IskandarRezaRazali - yeah I attempted that but again I'm hiding all divs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a simple condition:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {

  // if value IS more than zero, add some html
  if(value>0){
    html += '<div class="col-lg-2 panel ' + key + ' ">';
    html += '<p>' + key + '</p>';
    html += '<label>' + value + '</label>';
    html += '</div>';
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed this - I was putting the condition outside the loop and using if(value ===0)